# How can I create multiple bar charts at once (in R)?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a data set that includes Likert-type ratings of a bunch of around 20 measures. In my head I have an image of one long chart with 20 plots showing the distribution for each question.

Using something along the lines of:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 v2 = c(2,4,2,4,3),
                 v3 = c(1,1,1,1,2))
```

Is it possible to create a set of plots (either histogram or other distribution plot) to make it easy to compare these?

Comment: You are asking a lot and have not provided much. You're going to need to provide a more concrete example, and a description of a specific issue that came up in the process.

Comment: what is the problem, creating one plot or replicating a plot 20 times? `par(mfrow = c(1,3)); sapply(df, barplot)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! rawr's comment was a step in the right direction:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
colnames <- dimnames(df)[[2]]
for (i in 1:3) {
    hist(df[,i], main=colnames[i], probability = TRUE)
}
```